# When should I create a separate module file in NodeJS?

Tags: c#, node.js, oop, node-modules, commonjs

I have a lot of experience with traditional object oriented programing (mostly C#), and am now learning NodeJS. I understand how CommonJS modules work in NodeJS, but I'm confused how to map my existing understanding of how to architect software using C# classes and assemblies to NodeJS modules.

In traditional OOP everything is a class, and each class is typically one file. Many classes are then compiled into an assembly.

A NodeJS module is always only one file, which is like a class (most of the time). However, only one instance of a module is ever created in a running application which is very much not like a class. So in a sense modules feel more like a C# namespaces. A module can also contain multiple classes/function constructors like a C# namespace can contain multiple classes.

However, a module is also always one file. If I were to port an existing C# application to NodeJS it would feel wrong to move all the logic in many class files under a single namespace into one massive module file. But maybe I'm just accustomed to many small class files?

Are there best practices or conventions for when code should be split into separate modules files when programing in NodeJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript you should mostly be thinking in terms of functions. For every functionality you write a function. If a function is too big, break it down in smaller function and create a new function which calls all the smaller functions. Generally we keep functions which are written around same functionality for e.g. user management, in single file.

It is also a common practice to keep all the similar files in a single folder and then adding index.js file which imports all the files in that folder into the index.js and index.js uses all the imported files and create final interface which can be used by other modules directly instead of importing every single file. It's hard to explain in words but you can see these examples, just look at the exports statements there and see the file structure:

https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/lib/router

https://github.com/axios/axios/tree/master/lib

Hope this helps.Happy learning...